# Fiberglass camper plus steel trailer

Tags: structural-engineering, materials

Hello to all of you with more expertise about engineering than me...and anyone else that is curious.

I like to fantasize about projects, so this may be more of a thought experiment, but I'll throw it out there.

If I were to have a camper trailer, the camper is made primarily of fiberglass, and the supporting trailer is steel, How would I go about connecting the two?  If I just bolt it on there, I expect the camper part would get ripped apart because the the elasticity of the two materials is so different.  Flexing in the steel frame would just rip the fiberglass apart...no?

I assume when the trailer experiences forces from bumps in the road, the steel will flex, but the fiberglass wont, or at least will flex in a totally different way.

---

Comment: Corvettes have held together pretty well ( and I guess also Avantis ).

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue as old as the time of roman carriages or earlier.

Basically you need to design the joint connecting the two different structures using both smart design anticipating vibrations and concentrated stresses and utilizing impact damping rubber pads, coil springs, or system of links and levers designed to absorb the intense forces of the road before transferring them to the camper.

And the camper has to have structurally reinforced shell with additional thick wall and struts with fiberglass ribs getting thicker and stronger leading a connection joint to the steel suspensions.

A good example to observe is the driver cab of semi trucks. The cab is fiber glass but the chassis and suspension steel. If you walk around you see how they are connected through a system of rubber links, shock absorbers, coil springs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You design it so the two parts move together, but can distort individually in different ways.

The simplest way is to use six links between the two parts with ball joints at each end, arranged so they will restrain the three translations and the rotations of one part relative to the other.

Adding "rubber links, shock absorbers, coil springs, etc" may be nice design features for other reasons but it is not necessary to solve the basic engineering problem you posed. For example, jet engines are fixed to aircraft this way without any of these additions, because the engine expands by a few millimeters as it heats up when it is running, but the aircraft does not, and it would be a very bad idea if the relative expansion caused any distortion or high stress levels in either the engine or the airframe.

(Real aircraft engine mounting systems can be a bit more complicated than just 6 links because they have to be fail-safe if something breaks, but that doesn't affect the basic design concept.)

Answer (score 0):

No. Why would the steel frame want to flex *differently* from (pull apart) the chassis? What is loading the frame causing it to bend, other than the chassis? The frame can only aide in supporting the chassis. It can't pull it apart. The suspension system limits the rate of load changes so that this is effectively a statics problem, with the chassis and floor loading the frame. The frame is responding to and resisting these loads. Tanks are secured to the frame directly and near the axles. There aren't any loads causing the frame to bend the chassis except for levelling jacks and some junk in the storage bays.

The steel frame on my trailer is about 3/16 inch thick, 12" deep, 3" flange I-beams at the axles. The chassis structure is welded aluminum tube. If I support opposite corners, I can rack the trailer about 3 degrees over 30 feet. This on a 15,000#, 37 foot fifth wheel. The frame sections are smaller at the ends. A quicky calc suggests the frame deflection from a 2 ton point load half way between the hitch and the axles is about 1/8 inch. (I carry a bit of junk around with me.)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one answer to this.  A pickup's bed is bolted to the frame.  But a Unimog bed is attached allowing articulation because of the extreme wheel travel and MB's decision to not build a completely rigid frame.  Semi cabs are not just bolted to the frame, but a pickup's is.

What does this mean for your camper?  I think you will find that camper frames are typically built for minimal flex, and the composite bodies are tightly bolter to them.  The exception will be offroad campers that will experience a lot of weird bending from uneven wheel loads.